# Combinatorial best match

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, mathematical-optimization

Say I have a `Group` data structure which contains a list of `Element` objects, such that each group has a *unique set* of elements.:

```
public class Group
{
  public List<Element> Elements;
}
```

and say I have a list of populations who require certain elements, in such a way that each population has a *unique set* of required elements:

```
public class Population
{
  public List<Element> RequiredElements;
}
```

I have an unlimited quantity of each defined Group, i.e. they are *not consumed* by populations.

Say I am looking at a particular `Population`. I want to find the *best possible match* of groups such that there is minimum excess elements, and *no unmatched elements*.

For example: I have a population which needs wood, steel, grain, and coal. The only groups available are {wood, herbs}, {steel, coal, oil}, {grain, steel}, and {herbs, meat}.

The last group - {herbs, meat} isn't required at all by my population so it isn't used. All others are needed, but herbs and oil are not required so it is wasted. Furthermore, steel exists twice in the minimum set, so one lot of steel is also wasted. The *best match* in this example has a wastage of 3.

So for a few hundred `Population` objects, I need to find the *minimum wastage best match* and compute how many elements are wasted.

How do I even begin to solve this? Once I have found a match, counting the wastage is trivial. Finding the match in the first place is hard. I could enumerate all possibilities but with a few thousand populations and many hundreds of groups, it's quite a task. Especially considering this whole thing sits inside each iteration of a simulated annealing algorithm.

I'm wondering whether I can formulate the whole thing as a mixed-integer program and call a solver like GLPK at each iteration.

I hope I have explained the problem correctly. I can clarify anything that's unclear.

---

Here's my binary program, for those of you interested...

`x` is the decision vector, an element of {0,1}, which says that the population in question does/doesn't receive from group i. There is an entry for each group.

`b` is the column vector, an element of {0,1}, which says which resources the population in question does/doesn't need. There is an entry for each resource.

`A` is a matrix, an element of {0,1}, which says what resources are in what groups.

The program is:

Minimise: ((Ax - b)' * 1-vector) + (x' * 1-vector);

Subject to: Ax >= b;

The constraint just says that all required resources must be satisfied. The objective is to minimise all excess and the total number of groups used. (i.e. 0 excess with 1 group used is better than 0 excess with 5 groups used).

Comment: How many unique types of groups are there or rather what is the maximum number of unique groups that can exist?  What is the maximum number of elements that each population can use?  If these numbers are on the small side, then you might be able to brute force a solution by iterating through all of the possible unique group combinations and keeping track of the smallest wastage.

Comment: As I said in my question, there are thousands of each type. Furthermore, I need to solve this problem exactly for each iteration of my SA algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can formulate an integer program for each population `P` as follows. Use a binary variable x<sub>j</sub> to denote whether group j is chosen or not. Let A be a binary matrix, such that A<sub>ij</sub> is 1 if and only if item i is present in group j. Then the integer program is:

min *E*<sub>i,j</sub> (x<sub>j</sub>A<sub>ij</sub>)

s.t. *E*<sub>j</sub> x<sub>j</sub>A<sub>ij</sub> >= 1 for all i in `P`.

x<sub>j</sub> = 0, 1     for all j.

Note that you can obtain the minimum wastage by subtracting `|P|` from the optimal solution of the above IP.

Comment: Thanks, I already have an IP formulation which solves this - but I was hoping not to have to call the solver at each iteration of my SA :(

Comment: I don't think it's possible to avoid calling the IP at each iteration when the populations and the groups are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the [Maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximal_matchings) problem?

You need to build a [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), where one of the sides is your populations and the other is groups, and edge exists between group A and population B if it have it in its set.

To find maximum **edge** matching you can easily use Kuhn algorithm, which is greatly described [here on TopCoder](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=684427&start=0&mc=10#1276996).
But, if you want to find mimimum edge dominating set (the set of minimum edges that is covering all the vertexes), the problem becomes NP-hard and can't be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: I'm afraid, that both of your modelling approaches are not helpful for the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the weighted set cover problem, I think this is exactly what you described above. A basic description of the (unweighted) problem can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover).

Finding the minimal waste as you defined above is equivalent to finding a set cover such that the sum of the cardinalities of the covering sets is minimal. Hence, the weight of each set (=a group of elements) has to be defined equal to its cardinality.

Since even the unweighted the set cover problem is NP-complete, it is not likely that an efficient algorithm for your problem instances exist. Maybe a good greedy approximation algorithm will be sufficient or your purpose? Googling weighted set cover provides several promising results, e.g. this [script](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/880-S07/scribe-notes/lecture03.pdf).